# Generate X/0 pattern with random number (no hardcode)

Tags: java

I would like to generate a certain pattern using a random number between 1 and 4. The patterns look like the following:

```
1 = X000000000
2 = X0000X0000
3 = X00X00X000
4 = X0X0X0X000
```

Basically the random number indicates, how many X's are going to be used in the pattern and the 0 will fill up at regular intervals.

Is there a way to generate those patterns without using hardcoded variables?

**Edit**

Since it appearently isn't easy to understand i write everything in DETAIL here: im using following code to define what the programm has to output for each number which is randomly generated:

```
 if (i == 1){
 System.println("X000000000");
 if (i == 2){
 System.println("X0000X0000");
 if (i == 3){
 System.println("X00X00X000");
 if (i == 4){
 System.println("X0X0X0X000");
```

Is there a way to use a method which doesn't include using hardcoded if questions?

The patterns for 1-4 are always gonna stay like this. It depends on which number is generated, what to output.

Comment: What part of it is random?

Comment: Yes, you can but you need to add more details on how this pattern should look like.

Comment: Which places should the X occupy?

Comment: `Regular Intervals` ? I can't see that.

Comment: So the idea is to keep consistent spacing with the maximum amount of space possible in 10 characters?

Comment: @shmosel the only random part in the process is generating the patterns to the randomly generated number between 1-4 the patterns are always gonna stay the same. But right now im using hardcode to define that 1 has this pattern, 2 has this pattern and so on... i would like to have a solution without hardcoding the patterns for each number.

Comment: Are 1-4 the only options? Do you know how to generate a random number?

Comment: Represent them as binary numbers and convert the bits dynamically from 0 and 1 to 0 and X. For example, the first pattern becomes 1024

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(generatePattern(1, 10));
    System.out.println(generatePattern(2, 10));
    System.out.println(generatePattern(3, 10));
    System.out.println(generatePattern(4, 10));
}

public static String generatePattern(int count, int length) {
    int frequency = length / count;
    StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        pattern.append(i % frequency == 0 && i < frequency * count ? 'X' : '0');
    }
    return pattern.toString();
}
```

Output:

```
X000000000
X0000X0000
X00X00X000
X0X0X0X000
```

Comment: Thank you very much thats exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient , you can try this too

```
public String randomShuffle(int countOfX) {
        String allX = "XXXXXXXXXX";
        int localCount = 0;
        List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (char c : allX.toCharArray()) {
            if(localCount < countOfX){
                characters.add(c);
                localCount++;
            }else{
                characters.add('0');
            }

        }
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(allX.length());
        while (characters.size() != 0) {
            int randPicker = (int) (Math.random() * characters.size());
            output.append(characters.remove(randPicker));
        }
        //System.out.println(output.toString());
        return output.toString();
    }
```